# is the OS a process itself?

Tags: process, operating-system

I am recently develop a big interest to learn about operating systems and I have been studying about this topic, I have a question that I am not pretty sure if is a valid one.

I am aware that the OS is the one who controls the process but,

`is the OS a process itself? If so, who controls the OS?`

Sorry for my ignorance I am learning about operating system and I am trying to have a solid idea about how it works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a *lot* of different ways to answer your question. On the one hand, nothing "controls" the OS. On the other hand, you could say the processor "controls" the OS, or you could say the firmware "controls" the OS. It's a great question but very difficult to answer without the appropriate background.

Comment: What is your practical programming problem? This appears to be theoretical at this point.

Comment: I disagree that it's a great question for StackOverflow -- great questions are sufficiently well-defined as to limit their scope to something that can be answered in Q&A form. Also, StackOverflow is focused on questions about *programming*, not computer science, and not theory; we have separate StackExchange sites for those other topics.

Answer (score 8):

The term OS comes with some ambiguities... Does the user interface count as the OS? What about software that reads file systems?

The Kernel is generally the most important aspect of an Operating System. The Kernel is responsible for scheduling threads and processes, as well as abstracting the hardware from the software. The kernel itself is *NOT* a process, but it is a program. It's a program that always exists in every process space. When a process needs to access hardware, the kernel takes over and returns a response to the process. When the process's allotted time on the CPU is over, the kernel takes over and gives the CPU to a new process.

Other aspects of an Operating System, however, are their own processes. For example, on Windows, the user interface and many background services are their own processes. On Linux and other UNIX-like operating systems, the User Interfaces are also in their own respective processes, and in some cases things like filesystem drivers are in their own process as well, sometimes this is considered a hardware abstraction and is therefore placed in the kernel.

There are many possible design choices, however when it comes down to it there will always be a part of the operating system (the Kernel) that will never be it's own process.

Answer (score 0):

The OS is a bunch of processes. It is started up during the boot process. How the boot process works depends on the system. But generally, the boot process is also a process whose sole job is to start up the OS.

The OS is generally specific to the hardware it runs on. A main function of the OS is to be a layer between the hardware and application programs. Which processes in the OS are used depend on what functions the application programs need to do.

Comment: *"The OS is generally specific to the hardware it runs on."* pretty sure Windows/Ubuntu/etc. aren't specific to the hardware they run on...

Comment: Try running Windows on a TI-99.

Comment: I think by "hardware" you mean "CPU". Windows (desktop version) runs on a *great* variety of hardware, but only x86 CPUs.

Comment: I meant hardware. CPU is a hardware component. What I did not say was that a particular OS runs only on a particular platform. It seems like that's what you read from what I said. Some OS's will run on a wide variety of hardware, but are still *generally* specific to hardware.

Comment: What OSes did you have in mind if not Linux/Windows/Macs then? The "OS" behind a TI-99?

Comment: I didn't have specific OS's in mind. The question was a generic one, so I answered generically. In punch card days, the computer didn't use an OS. The program was loaded by punch cards and monopolized the computer. Since then, there have been myriad OS's. In modern times, most hardware is standardized for compatibility, but that hasn't always been the case. Other OS's I was generically thinking of included Palm OS and the OS running in my camera.

Comment: I think you're missing my point. The hardware-specific part of the OS is **not** even part of the OS -- it's the drivers supplied by the device manufacturer. Aside from a relatively few very fundamental pieces of hardware which the OS has to know about (the CPU, clock, etc.), the OS itself supplies a framework for these drivers which is pretty independent of the hardware it runs on. Saying the OS is hardware-dependent is plain wrong, it's the drivers that are hardware-dependent and their *job* is to make an OS hardware-independent.

Comment: I guess that depends on whether you think device drivers are part of the OS or not. Generally, they are usually considered as part of the OS. See the wikipedia article, for example. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system

Comment: The very article you linked to explicitly counters your argument: *"**The key design goal of device drivers is abstraction**. Every model of hardware (even within the same class of device) is different. Newer models also are released by manufacturers that provide more reliable or better performance and these newer models are often controlled differently. Computers and their **operating systems cannot be expected to know how to control every device**."*  This sentence makes absolutely zero sense if you think drivers are "part of the OS". The OS is hardware independent. The driver isn't.

Comment: You should learn the difference between "explicitly" and "implicitly". Also, the implication is not there. Just because an OS can't know how to control every device doesn't mean it can't know how to control many devices. A single Windows installation disk can be used to install the OS on hundreds of different hardware platforms. For some esoteric ones you may have to download third party drivers and integrate them into the OS, but most of them are already included.

Comment: This question, by the way, is addressed here: http://superuser.com/questions/447048/are-drivers-part-of-the-operating-systems

Comment: Windows and Linux only "include" drivers because that's convenient. They don't need to, and for almost all drivers, they could very well avoid shipping the drivers and still claim they're shipping a fully functional OS. Even the answer you linked to has comments that disagree with your reasoning.

Comment: Of course it does. It also contains points that disagree with you. So what? My point in citing it is that I believe it's in a better place for this discussion than here. I'm with Raymond that the question starting this whole thread probably should not be here at all. Rather than drag on this discussion for which it seems like we're at an impasse, I'd suggest it be continued there instead, if at all.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on design approaches.
According to 3.5 section of "Operating Systems Internal and Design Principles - 7th edition" textbook (written by William Stalling), there are 3 approaches:

1. non-process kernel.

In this approach, user process and kernel are separate.

**process image** = address space + PCB = (code + data + stack + heap) + PCB

2. Execution within User Process

In this approach, some common functions of Operation Systems (run in kernel mode) belong to User processes.

**process image** = PCB + user address space + kernel address space = PCB + (user code + user data + user stack + user heap) + (kernel code + kernel data + kernel stack + kernel heap).

3. Process-Based Operating System.

In this approach Operating System is a collection of system processes, each system process executes in kernel mode, and is in charge of specific function.

In addition, these system processes separate with user processes.

Best Regards

Viet Nam.